# Can't resume after hibernation

Tags: lightdm, hibernate

I tried to hibernate using `pm-hibernate` but when I start Ubuntu again I can't get to login screen.but when i tried to login `lightdm` keeps restarting and keeping me from login .

please help me?
I'm new to ubuntu.

`sudo startx`

```
Fetal server error:
Server is already active for display 0
if this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock and start again
ddSignGiveUp: Closing log
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 KeyInvalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 Keyxinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Resource temporarily unavaliable
xinit: server error
```

Answer (score 1):

What laptop do you have? Also, next time this happens try ctrl + alt + F2 and login. Then try

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

You may need this in your grub config.

So in the terminal (ctrl + T) enter

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

then find this line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash″
```

and change that to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet nox2apic splash″
```

then save the file and close. Then in the terminal again type.

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot.

Comment: I have Hp pavilion Dv6- 6b80ee. dual boot(ubuntu + windows)
the problem is i can't x session (no GUI).lightdm kepps restarting.all i have right now is console (ctrl + alt + F2)

Comment: it's not working.any suggestion?

Comment: Can you provide an log? Have you tried "startx" from the command line?

Comment: I did
>>sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg
then reboot
>>startx -- :1
and now it's working.
thanks for your help :)